# Android: Using deep link from API response while app is in foreground

Tags: android, lifecycle, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

I'm using an SDK and need to handle a deep link from an API call when the app has started. I'm using navigation component for my deep linking. I've found that when I get the deep link from the call and pass it to navigation component handleDeeplink() after setContentView was called, the app doesn't navigate even if handleDeeplink validates the deep link. Other than loading an intent with the deep link and restarting the activity, how can I use the deep link to navigate to the correct content after the fact?

Comment: Did you override `onNewIntent()` and are you handling the deeplink in there as well as in `onCreate()`?